# Hiding the stereotype

Tags: enterprise-architect

We have created an MDG by extending the features of interface. We have an element called "Design" of type interface defined in MDG. On Selecting the toolbox and droping an element "Design" in the diagram we are getting an element with stereotype "Design" in diagram . On Right Click of diagram and selecting the Advance properties of elements and tries to uncheck the show element stereotype. After unchecking the property the diagram is hiding the stereotype and replacing the sterotype "Design" with stereotype «interface» .So how can we even hide the "interface" in Diagram

Answer (score 1):

«Interface» is not a stereotype but a keyword (although visually the same).

You can hide that by choosing **Advanced | Use Circle Notation**. Using the rectangular notation without the «interface» keyword would simply be wrong as you wouldn't be able to visually see the difference between a class and an interface.

If you want to completely create your own visualization then you'll have to use a shapescript on your stereotype.